# plt.show() does not show the 3d scatter image

Tags: python, matplotlib

community,

I tried to create the 3d scatter by using matplotlib Axes3D on jupyter notebook. 
However, it is not showing the image once I execute 'plt.show()'.

```
#pip install matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure()
ax =fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x = dframe['CTR']
y = dframe['Clicks']
z = dframe['Avg. CPC']
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code looks a bit weird to me. What is the use of line `%matplotlib inline`. I tried reproducing your issue but I got `NameError: name 'dframe' is not defined`. Can you please edit your question and add more details and please add a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: it works for me with x=y=z = [1,2,3]. Perhaps something wrong with your data ?

Comment: can you show us your dframe?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine like this:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

# dummy data (your actual data should go here)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x
z = x
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c="r", marker="o")
plt.show()
```

This shows:

[image]

May be something is wrong with your data. Also, since you are using `plt.show()` anyway, you can remove the `%matplotlib inline` line.